# A question about extending Lebesgue measure to all subsets of the real numbers.

Tags: measure-theory

Is it known to be consistent with just ZF set theory-without the Axiom of Choice-that there exists an extension of Lebesgue measure to all subsets of real numbers, which is countably additive and isometrically invariant?.....I am confused about this because some articles in the literature, which seem to imply that my question has a "yes" answer, also seem to add a Large Cardinal Axiom to the axioms of ZF. But my question specifically rules out any axioms beyond those of ZF.

Comment: Related: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/211507/measurability-and-axiom-of-choice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is known that the consistency of "All sets of reals are Lebesgue measurable" over $ZF+DC$ has large cardinal strength; however, note the role of $DC$, Dependent Choice, in the base theory. With many related results, dropping the requirement of $DC$ also drops the consistency strength of the related regularity property. For example, I believe $ZF$+"All sets have the perfect set property" is equiconsistent with $ZFC$ (Truss, although I can't find the citation right now), whereas $ZF+DC$+"All sets have the perfect set property" has the same consistency strength as an inaccessible (Shelah).

The problem is that - unlike e.g. the perfect set property - it's not $100\%$ clear how to define Lebesgue measurability if we drop the axiom of dependent choice, since now the countable union of countable sets need not be countable! So my instinct is that you'll get wildly varying answers, depending on what definition of "Lebesgue measurable" you use, reflecting the fact that these definitions are *not* equivalent over mere $ZF$.

Comment: Let EML denote the statement about the existence of Lebesgue Measure for all sets of real numbers, which is a part of my question. Your answer, if I understand it correctly, then implies that my question has a "no" answer. We do not know if EML is consistent with ZF(or with ZF+DC) because we do not know if any Large Cardinal Axiom is consistent with ZF (or with ZF+DC).....Incidentally I am not quite clear about what it means-given two formalized theories A,B-to state that "A and B have the same consistency strength".

Comment: @GarabedGulbenkian No, you're misunderstanding my answer. The point is that - while assuming at least DC, it's clear what "Lebesgue measurable" should mean - over ZF it's not clear exactly how to *state* "every set is Lebesgue measurable" since some of the definitions are no longer equivalent.

Comment: Re: consistency strength, when we say that $A$ and $B$ have the same consistency strength (or, are equiconsistent), what we mean is that a very weak theory - say, PA, but we can go even weaker - proves "$A$ is consistent iff $B$ is consistent". Classic examples include: $ZFC$ and $ZF+\neg AC$; $ZFC$ and $ZFC+V=L$; $ZFC+$"There is an inaccessible" and $ZF+DC+$"All sets are measurable"; etc. Meanwhile, we can prove that large cardinals represent an increase in consistency strength over ZFC: if $PA$ proves "$ZFC$ is consistent iff $ZFC+$"An inaccessible" is consistent," then $ZFC$'s inconsistent.

Comment: Proof of this last claim, assuming $PA$ is true (or at least correct about $\Sigma^0_1$ sentences): $ZFC+I$ proves $Con(ZFC)$. So if $Con(ZFC)$ implied $Con(ZFC+I)$, this would mean $ZFC+I$ proved $Con(ZFC+I)$, contradicting Godel - unless $ZFC+I$ is inconsistent! So if $PA$ proves that $Con(ZFC)$ implies $Con(ZFC+I)$, then $PA$ proves $\neg Con(ZFC+I)$; so combining these two statements, $PA$ proves $\neg Con(ZFC)$. Since $PA$ is true, that means $ZFC$ is inconsistent!

Comment: Many thanks for this detailed explanation which will give me a lot to think about.

Comment: I have one question about an example you present in your explanation of consistency strength. "If PA proves Con(ZFC+I) implies Con(ZFC) then ZFC is inconsistent". Surely one does not need PA to prove Con(ZFC+I) implies Con(ZFC). Since ZFC is a sub-theory of ZFC+I, if ZFC+I is consistent then the basic rules of first order logic should force ZFC to be consistent also. What am I missing here?

Comment: @GarabedGulbenkian Other way round. I'm talking about the implication "If $ZFC$ is consistent, then $ZFC+I$ is consistent." This implication cannot be proved in $PA$ (hopefully).

Comment: It still seems as though the answer to my original question is "no". Since I do not want to work in any set theory more inclusive than ZFC, and-in particular-do not want to bring in Large Cardinal Axioms, my question could be stated as: " Can it be proved (in PA) that Con(ZFC) implies Con(ZF+DC+ELM)?. The answer is "no" or at least "no such proof has yet been obtained"  The best one can do is to bring in a Large Cardinal Axiom and prove Con(ZFC+I) implies Con(ZF+DC+ELM).

Comment: The answer to your reformulated question is indeed **no** - as long as $ZFC+I$ is consistent. This was the point of my comment, and is due to Shelah (in the paper "Can you take Solovay's inaccessible away?"). Specifically, we have: $(i)$ PA proves $ZF+DC+EML$ is consistent iff $ZFC+I$ is consistent; $(ii)$ $PA$ does *not* prove "If $ZFC$ is consistent, then $ZFC+I$ is consistent" (unless $PA$ proves that $ZFC$ is inconsistent, which we hope it doesn't).

Comment: Crucially, it's not just that we don't *know* how to get rid of the inaccessible - it's that we *know we can't*. $PA$ proves $Con(ZF+DC+ELM)$ implies $Con(ZFC+I)$ (this was Shelah's paper; the converse implication was Solovay's). So, combining this with the observation in my comments above, we have: $PA$ **cannot** prove $Con(ZFC)$ implies $Con(ZF+DC+ELM)$, unless $PA$ proves that $ZFC$ is inconsistent.

Comment: But note that $DC$ is playing a crucial role here. Without $DC$, things are much murkier - in particular, you have to be very very careful how you even express "$ELM$."